How many pointers does java LinkedHashMap/Set Entry object have
In Java HashSet, When collision occurs, the HashMap stores multiple entries in the same bucket using a linked list.
Then in case of LinkedHashSet, LinkedHashMap will have a pointer to the next inserted element as well.
so does each entry object will have multiple pointers? one to point the elements in the same bucket and the other to point the next inserted element?

Have you tried looking at the source?

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java

Technically, there are also pointers to the key and to the value.  Look at the implementation and decide how many pointers count.
The answer you're probably looking for is three: one to the next in the bucket, one to the previous entry in insertion order, and one to the next entry in insertion order.
